# Angular. Manually updating property with HostBinding decorator

Tags: angular

I have a component with HostBinded property that I want to update manually from other components. I wrote it like this:

```ts
private _selected: boolean = false;
@HostBinding('class.selected')
get selected(): boolean {
    return this._selected;
}
set selected(value: boolean) {
    if (this._selected === value) {
        return;
    }
    this._selected = value;
    this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}
```

I have two problems with it.

**First**. When I try to update property for `ContentChild` - changes are not applied. See example here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-changes-ignored-contentchildren-hostbinding:

```
@ContentChildren(ItemComponent) items: QueryList<ItemComponent>;

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.updateItems();
  this.items.changes.subscribe(() => {
    this.updateItems();
  });

  this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}
private updateItems() {
  this.items.forEach(item => {
    item.selected = this.selected === item.value;
  });
}
```

If I add

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
});
```

then UI will be updated but I don't understand why its needed.

**Second**. When I try to update property for `ViewChild` - ExpressionChanged error is thrown. Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expression-has-changed-viewchild-hostbinding.

```
@ViewChild(ItemComponent) item: ItemComponent;

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.item.selected = true;
  this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}
```

Again why? Usually `markForCheck` call prevents the error.

Comment: is it obligation for you to add your class `.selected` directly on component tag ? Or i can prupose solution to play around ?

Comment: Actually I want to understand what's wrong or rather why it works that way than simply how to avoid error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding **second**. Error is thrown because of [the nature of ngAfterViewInit](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10131) - it is run after change detection cycle and any change here will trigger the error (in dev mode only). But there are few interesting moments.

As I used `OnPush` strategy  `markForCheck` actually triggered the error, if all calls to it are removed then no error will be shown and no changes will be applied either.

Other thing is that `markForCheck` apparently doesn't trigger new round of change detection when it already in action.

So solution would be either to apply changes in `ngOnInit` hook as it runs before change detection and `ViewChild` is available there. Or to call `detectChanges` insetad of `markForChek` as it triggers new change detection cycle.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-expression-has-changed-viewchild

**First** one. This case differs from previous - now there are three components: App, List and Item. Item and List are created in App's template, then Item projected inside List.

First of all `detectChanges` inside List's `ngAfterViewInit` will not update Item, probably because Item is not direct child  or parent of List. Moreover calling `markForCheck` will not trigger error (as in **second** case) without calling `markForCheck` in App's `ngAfterViewInit`.

Correct way is to apply changes inside List's `ngAfterContentInit`.This hook runs before change detection and everything will be correctly rendered into the dom.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-changes-ignored-contentchildren